# There exists a triangle with all edges of the same colour.

Tags: combinatorics

Let there be a pyramid with a nonagonal base. The lateral edges and the diagonals of the base are drawed with black or  red.

I have to show that there exists a triangle with all edges of the same colour.

I have no idea how can I start.

Comment: How many edges are there? Nine from the top of the pyramid and nine around the base, or also more edges in the interior of the base?

Comment: @Servaes I interpret "the ***diagonals*** of the base" to mean that the $27$ "Interior edges" ***are*** coloured, but the $9$ edges around the base are ***not*** coloured.

Comment: @Servaes The edges of the base are not coloured, just the diagonals.

Comment: @Sorry for this late comment, but I try to understand the posted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $V$ is a peak of pyramid then $V$ is connected with at least 5 different base points with the same color say black. If two of these 5 are connected with black diagonal then we are done.

So suppose each pair of these 5 points which is connected is connected with red diagonal. Now it is not difficult to see that some 3 of them are not such that are pair vise not neighbour. So these 3 make a red triangle.

Comment: I may be wrong, but I interpret "the lateral edges and the *diagonals* of the base" to mean an edge colouring not of $K_{10}$ but of $K_{10}-C_9.$

Comment: If $K_n-C_n\to(K_3,K_3)$ is what we want, then $n=9$ is best possible. So my interpretation explains why the base of the pyramid is a $9$-gon rather than a $5$-gon.

Comment: The point of my last comment was that $K_8-C_8\not\to(K_3,K_3).$ It took me some time to figure out a colouring for that. Is it obvious?

Comment: @ChristianF Can you explain with more details? I tried to understand your idea but I can't. There exists an elementary proof?

Comment: I have made an edit.